# How to check a permission value of a text channel? [discord.py]

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to check if a text channel already has a permission set to a certain value, specifically the **send_messages** permission. Basically I want something like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def perm(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel = None)
if (send_messages = False):
        # If permission is set to false, print error message
        ctx.send("Permission is already set to false.")
else:
        # Else, set permission to false
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `overwrites_for` to get the [`PermissionOverwrite`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PermissionOverwrite) for the role.

```
@bot.command()
async def perm(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel):
    overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    if overwrite.send_messages == False:
        await ctx.send("Permission is already set to false.")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```