# Discord py Trying to skip over locked channels

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have tried so many channel permissions combinations. I cannot come up with anything to skip locked channels. I am trying to make a broadcast command that will send in the first open permission channel.

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def broadcast(self, ctx, *, msg):
        for guild in self.client.guilds:
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                if channel.permissions == discord.Permissions(permissions=8):
                    continue
                elif channel.permissions == discord.Permissions(permissions=0):
                    await channel.send(msg)
                else:
                    await print("Did not send")
                break
```

This is what I have as of right now.

My problem is I do not want to specify a channel as I am sending this to all of the servers.

These are the two edits I have made that did not work so far.

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def broadcast(self, ctx, *, msg):
        for guild in self.client.guilds:
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                if channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role).send_messages == False:
                    continue
                elif channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role).send_messages == None | True:
                    await channel.send(msg)
```

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def broadcast(self, ctx, *, msg):
        for guild in self.client.guilds:
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                if channel.permissions_for(ctx.guild.default_role).send_messages == False:
                    continue
                elif channel.permissions_for(ctx.guild.default_role).send_messages == None | True:
                    await channel.send(msg)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check a permission value of a text channel? \[discord.py\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402412/how-to-check-a-permission-value-of-a-text-channel-discord-py)

Comment: @Taku I tried a few things from this example, and it did not change anything. Thank you though.

Comment: The solution from that post is how you would check channel permissions in discord.py, which is the answer to your question. What did you change to your code to implement from that answer?

Comment: @Taku I will edit the post to show the changes I tried.

Comment: Remove your `elif`, and python `|` is not `or`.

Answer (score 0):

use a try except loop. It will try to send a message to the channel, and if it can't, it will go to the next channel.

```
@commands.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def broadcast(self, ctx, *, msg):
    for guild in self.client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.text_channels:
            try:
                channel.send(msg)
            except:
                pass
```